# What if professors I mentioned in my PhD application are not accepting students

Tags: phd, application, computer-science

I recently applied to US universities and contacted professors I mentioned in the application. In one particular case (the most important one), all three professors are not accepting students. Would the application get rejected straight away?
My research area as mentioned in my SOP is “*Deep Learning and its applications in Computer Vision*”.

I guess the area I mentioned in my SOP is neither too broad nor too restrictive. Does it affect the application in any way?

Answer (score 1):

Being rejected for that is  unlikely in the US as long as you are willing to be flexible. If you have only a bachelors when you start then the question of a dissertation advisor won't really arise for a few years and the situation might be different then.

Even with a masters, you probably need to pass comprehensive exams first so there is some time. And, again, if you are happy to work with someone else there won't be an issue.

The only real negative in this is if you have been so strong in your SoP that they think you will reject an offer out of hand, but I don't see that as especially likely.

If you get a chance to speak with anyone, say in an interview, just don't be rigid about advisors.

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily "straight away", but US graduate programs want to admit both:

1. Strong students with a high potential for success in graduate school and beyond
2. Students that fit well with the specific graduate program

If you name people you are interested in working with, and none of these people are taking students while you're a student, then that doesn't seem to me like a good "fit". If you're going to name people to work with, you should contact those people ahead of time; if they aren't taking students, there's no reason to mention them in your application. If there's no one at a given institution that you want to work with who is also taking students, then you should apply somewhere else that has a better fit of mentors to advise you.

As Buffy mentions, though, the program may see things differently if they expect incoming students to not find a mentor right away. If the program invites you for interviews, that may be a time to emphasize the breadth of your interests and take a chance to meet other faculty who could be possible mentors (if indeed your interests are broad; don't become the next Academia.SE user to post "I joined a lab in a topic I didn't like and now I don't like my topic, what should I have done differently?").